# SSO not working on ASP.NET WebApi self hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a SSO provided by IIS ASP.NET MVC 5 Web App and it works with the ASP.NET WebApi project hosted on IIS, but the same Startup.cs is not working on ASP.NET WebApi self hosted.

A Controller behind `[Authorize]` gives me `HTTP 401`.

This is the WebApi shared Startup.cs, I report only the authentication section.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    CookieName = "xxx",
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
});

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

app.SetDataProtectionProvider(new xxxDataProtectionProvider());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's Autorize or Authorize? Defile more code plz

Comment: Sorry it was a typo in the question, it's the Authorize attribute in the System.Net.Http namespace. What code do you need?

Comment: You've got both cookie and bearer auth enabled. Which are you using with the WebApi? You *should* be using bearer auth exclusively.

Comment: In the WebApi hosted on IIS they both work, in the self hosted I tried only the Cookie but it's not working, the bearer probably works fine because I had issues with the cookie on the IIS hosted too but I solved them with the DataProtectionProvider